# managment of many-to-many tags with Doctrine2

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am interested how tagging works. My idea so far:

I have three database tables `Bookmarks` `id|title|uri|…`, `Tags` `id|title|…` and bookmarks_tags (mxm, 3NF). My first test will be only a single-user system, so i have not to deal with Tags owned by specific users.

Storing a bookmark: `uri` (String) + `tags` (String, eg. `Lorem Ipsum, Hello` should result in two Tags: `Lorem Ipsum` and `Hello`).

Problem: Where and how should i create the missing `Tags` and loading the known ones?

Creating tags in the model is possible (see Bookmark::setTags() below). Loading and linking in the Model seems not possible, because the ORM is not available inside the class (or is there a static ressource for fetching the ORM? would this be recommended?).

I could load existing tags and create the tags inside `Controller`, but i assume tagging should be model's work.

I am using Symfony2 with Doctrine2.

**Bookmark Class/Table**

```
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="X\BookmarksBundle\Entity\BookmarkRepository")
 */
class Bookmark
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string $uri
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uri", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $uri;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var datetime $deleted_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $deleted_at;


    /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) */
    private $tags;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getTags () {
        if ($this->tags->isEmpty()) {
            return "NO TAGS";
        }

        // TODO load tags from db
        return "TODO: TAGS FOUND";
    }

    public function setTags ($tags) {
        // TODO create and load/link existing tags
        $tag = new Tag();
        $tag->setTitle("test tag");
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    /* setters and getters for other private variables here */
```

**Tag Class/Table**

```
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="X\BookmarksBundle\Entity\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var datetime $deleted_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted_at;


    public function __construct () {
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime('now');
    }

        /* setters and getters for other private variables here */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fetching entities from your database, Doctrine2 don't give you the POPO Entity but a "Proxy". This proxy has the ability to load missing elements from the database. Thus, you don't have to implement the logic of retrieving the missing data from the database.

Btw, you can also create this method:

```
public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->add($tag);
}
```

Comment: how do i prevent to add a tag twice to the database? defining the title column unique does not count, because it would break the script on duplicated tags.

Checking tags before storing is no atomic operation.

Comment: Make a `$this->tags->has($tag)` check before calling `$this->tags->add($tag)`. This is solely for creating the relationship. If you're talking about the tags' table then this check should already have done before, perhaps in a controller.

Comment: Doing the duplicate check would break the boundary between model and controller though. You wouldn't be able to 'reuse' the model because some of the logic is missing.